# Javascript Array storage

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

Good morning;
I've started studying javascript for passion, and I'm really liking it! but I have a question on how to store values in an array. I tried to store 2 email addresses (through regular expression) and display the value stored every time, but I can only store one and the second prompt doesn't even run, can you help me? Thank youuu

```js
var myRE = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
var prompt = prompt("Your email addess");

if (myRE.test(prompt)) {
  alert("It's OK");
  var myArray = [prompt];
  alert(myArray[0]);
  var prompt1 = prompt("another one");

  if (myRE.test(prompt1)) {
    alert("It's OK");
    myArray.push(prompt1);
    alert(myArray[1]);

  } else {
    alert("Put a fckng mail man");
  };

} else {
  alert("Put a mail man");
}
```

Comment: Please can you better format the indentation of this code

Comment: `var prompt = prompt("Your email addess");` You have overriden the functional `prompt`,.

Comment: And please do not mention, Good morning, It is not morning in all parts of the world. Thank you.

Comment: The blatant swearing isn't exactly what I would consider 'good form' either.

Answer (score 3):

The javascript reference to the native browser function `prompt` is being overwritten by this line:

`var prompt = prompt("Your email addess");`

(now prompt is equal to the value returned and not the function that displays a window for the user to type in.)

Simply rename your variable to avoid this:

```
var anyOtherName = prompt("Your email address");
```

Now, next time you use prompt it will still be the function that displays a window.